# Signed APK crash with Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook

I got this error when I open my signed APK after login with Facebook:

```
03-20 13:53:31.202 29251-29251/com.play.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.play.myapp, PID: 29251
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.play.myapp/com.play.myapp.OnBoardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4141)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4184)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1563)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.play.myapp.OnBoardActivity$1.onError(OnBoardActivity.java:79)
                                                                   at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:636)
                                                                   at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:244)
                                                                   at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:173)
                                                                   at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:95)
                                                                   at com.play.myapp.OnBoardActivity.onActivityResult(OnBoardActivity.java:45)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6937)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4137)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4184) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1563) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

But nothing of this happen when I Run the app directly from Android Studio, so I really don't know what's happening.

I already add my Hash for debug and production on Facebook

This is my OnBoardActivity.java:

```
package com.play.Getcogas;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class OnBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager mSlideViewPager;
private LinearLayout mDotLayout;

private TextView[] mDots;

private SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;
private Button mNextBtn;
private AccessToken mAccessToken;
private int mCurrentPage;

private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_board);
    Log.d("start","Activity Start");

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginButton mLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    // Set the initial permissions to request from the user while logging in
    mLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email","user_birthday"));

    // Register a callback to respond to the user
    mLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("result","Successs");
            mAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            getUserProfile(mAccessToken);
            goToMainActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            System.out.println("onError");
            Log.v("LoginActivity", e.getCause().toString());
        }
    });

    mSlideViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.slideViewPager);
    mDotLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);


    mNextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);

    sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(this);
    mSlideViewPager.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
    addDotsIndicator(0);
    mSlideViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListener);
    mNextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            goToMainActivity();
        }
    });
}

private void getUserProfile(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            currentAccessToken,
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    //You can fetch user info like this…
                    try {
                        Log.d("name", object.getString("name"));
                        Log.d("fid", object.getString("id"));
                        Log.d("email", object.getString("email"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.width(200)");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
};

public void goToMainActivity(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}

public void addDotsIndicator(int position){
    mDots = new TextView[5];
    mDotLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < mDots.length; i++){
        mDots[i] = new TextView(this);
        mDots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        mDots[i].setTextSize(35);
        mDots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textLightDot));
        mDotLayout.addView(mDots[i]);
    }

    if(mDots.length > 0){
        mDots[position].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
}

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        addDotsIndicator(i);
        mCurrentPage = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
}
```

Not so sure If has something to do with my **build.gradle(Module:app)** or to be more specific, the signing part.

Because I add a Log to the Facebook error section and before crash I see that log, that means Facebook is not making the login.

This is my singingConfigs part:

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    Production {
        keyAlias 'projectKey'
        keyPassword '*******'
        storeFile file('/Users/personal/keystore')
        storePassword '*************'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.play.myapp"
    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "",
                            onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 16
    versionName "1.0.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    versionNameSuffix 'crw'
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.Production
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.Production
    }
}
```

To create the Production Hash I use on Mac:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias projectKey -keystore /Users/personal/keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

That show me the Hash with the warning that I need to migrate to **PKCS12** don't know if that it's part of the issue or its something that shows to everyone.

Everything works fine when I run the app directly from Android Studio, nothing show errors, everything works fine, this happens if I create a Debug or a Signed APK, so I really don't know if It's something on my code or I'm doing the Hash wrong and that's causing the crash, since this happens after the login and the Log cat error printed from the app.

Comment: From logs it looks like it's happening on your onActivityResult method on your OnBoardActivity.java class. Can you trigger this bug during development when running your app from Android Studio?

Comment: No, everything works fine from there, that's why I don't know what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look on this code:

```
   @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        System.out.println("onError");
        Log.v("LoginActivity", e.getCause().toString());
    }
```

this line is the problem:

```
 Log.v("LoginActivity", e.getCause().toString());
```

probably e.getCause() return null. Dont have idea why but removing above line should help.

Also you could check what hash this method will generate:

```
public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            Log.i(TAG, "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    }
}
```

Use it on RELASE version!

Comment: it's not that neither

Comment: It, weird because log is clearly that Throwable is null, "'java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.toString()' on a null object reference". also see edited answer

Comment: What's was wrong on the code was the Hash, Looks like I invert the passwords, after fix this, no more crash

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your proguard rules file, progurad code obfuscation is messing with FB's code

```
  -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepnames class com.facebook.FacebookActivity
-keepnames class com.facebook.CustomTabActivity

-keep class com.facebook.all.All

-keep public class com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService {
    public static com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService asInterface(android.os.IBinder);
    public android.os.Bundle getSkuDetails(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle);
}
```